# String Slicing with Negatives in Python

Tags: python

lets say I have this variable:

> a = "amazingjob"

and I want to slice the last three letters, but **I want to do it backwards/using negative numbers**, meaning:

> a[-1:-4]

I want the result to be **job**

Comment: What do you mean "won't this work"? What happens? And what do you want the result to be instead?

Comment: you just changed the requirements ...

Comment: hi rusu_ro1, you had it right in your comment earlier, I will upvote it if you comment it back. I did not think about using a negative step but I see how the implicit positive step is a problem for what I am doing

Comment: Do you want the output to be `"job"` or `"boj"`? Your question says one thing, but you seem to imply the other in your comment.

Comment: I want "job". The comments brought up a good point, that if I start from the last index, [-1:-4] python will reverse the string. But now that I tried it  [-1:-4:-1] skips the b and just prints "oj".

Comment: "if I start from the last index, [-1:-4] python will reverse the string." This is incorrect. Starting from the last index will return an empty string, not reverse the string.

Comment: "But now that I tried it [-1:-4:-1] skips the b and just prints "oj"" When I do `a[-1:-4:-1]`, I get "boj". The "b" isn't skipped. If you still need help, recreate what you did that dropped the "b" and we can help you understand why.

Comment: Thank you code-apprentice, you are right, I made mistake and that is why it skipped it.

Answer (score 2):

You should use in reverse order

```
a[-4:-1]
# gjo
```

you should actually use

```
a[-3:]
# job
```

if you want to reverse the string

```
a[-1:-4:-1]
# boj
```

Comment: So the reverse order will make Python read/slice my string from left to right, correct? Thanks for the input.

Comment: @128mbofram Yes, slicing starts from the first index and increments by 1 until the last index, taking each element that is calculated. So you usually want the smallest index first. In this case `-4` is less than `-1`, so it should be first.

Comment: basically the default step is 1. so when you are trying to use this step of 1 from -1, you cannot reach -4 index. So you have to use the start, end and step appropriately a[start_index, end_index, step]

Answer (score 2):

Slice notation is like this:

```
a[start:stop:step]
```

This gets the elements from index `start` up to (but not including) index `stop` incremented by `step`. By default `step` is 1, so you get an empty string since your `start` is already bigger than your `stop`.

Our first step is to fix the order of the indexes:

```
>>> a[-4:-1]
'gjo'
```

But this still isn't quite right. For negative indexing, the last character is at index `-1`, the next to the last at `-2`, etc. The best way to think about this is to get the last `n` characters of the string, you need to start at index `-n`. So let's starting at `-3` to get the last three characters:

```
>>> a[-3:-1]
'jo'
```

But we are still missing the last character. This is because the last index is not included in the slice. The last fix is to leave out the last index:

```
>>> a[-3:]
'job'
```

Leaving out the last index tells python to slice the string until the end of the string.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful too. For example, would you know why [-1:-4:-1] to get "boj", will skip the "b"?

Comment: @128mbofram `a[-1:-4:-1]` **doesn't** skip the "b" because the first index is included.